# How to set type of value send from a View selector in Angular 4?

Tags: typescript, ionic2, angular2-template, ionic3

I have this code for a simple number selector in my view:

```
<ion-select #pageSelector  [(ngModel)]="viewCurrentPageNumber" interface="popover" (ionChange)="newPageSelected($event)">
   <ion-option *ngFor="let number of renderTasks; let i = index" value="{{i+1}}">{{i+1}}</ion-option> 
</ion-select>
```

It just shows a selector with `1,2,3,4...renderTasks.length` and send the selected value to `newPageSelected()`

```
newPageSelected(pageNum : number) {
    console.log("newPageSelected()");

    console.log(`pageNum : ${pageNum} as  ${typeof pageNum}`);
    console.log("this.status.currentPageNum: " + this.status.currentPageNum + " as " + typeof this.status.currentPageNum);

    if(this.status.currentPageNum === pageNum) {
        console.log("pageNum is the same as the actual, nothing will be rendered.")
    } else {
        console.warn("loading")
        this.loadPage(pageNum);
    }
}
```

The thing is the `if` is always false because the console logs:

```
pageNum : 2 as  string 
this.status.currentPageNum: 1 as number
```

So obviously the `===` fails. Is there a way to set the type of the value send for the selector so I do not have to recheck it in the function (ie `pageNum = Number(pageNum)` ) or make the if comparison less strict ( `==` )

Comment: @sebaferreras Hi, thanks for comment. No, I want to force the value sended from the view to be of the correct type, I would prefer not to change `===` to `==`.

Comment: What happens if you change `value="{{i+1}}"` for `[value]="i+1"`?

Comment: @sebaferreras that did the trick! Could you post it as answer with the explanation to mark it as answer?

Comment: That's great... done! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not sure at first since a few months ago there were some issues related to this, but if you want to bind the `ion-select` to a number property, instead of using `value="{{i+1}}"`(since it's interpolation, that will result in a string) you would need to use attribute binding like this: `[value]="i+1"`

That way, the value of each ion-option would be bound to the object (a number in this scenario) and won't be converted to a string.

```
<ion-select #pageSelector  [(ngModel)]="viewCurrentPageNumber" interface="popover" (ionChange)="newPageSelected($event)">
   <ion-option *ngFor="let number of renderTasks; let i = index" [value]="i+1">{{i+1}}</ion-option> 
</ion-select>
```